# Regex to limit special character between range

Tags: java, regex

I want to limit special character to maximum value. Like I want the regex to limit at most 3 special character. I am using following regex, but its not working for me. :

```
(^(?:[^$@!%*?&\n]*[$@!%*?&]){0-2}[^$@!%*?&\n]*$)
```

Comment: This is utterly punishing to other developers who need to understand and maintain it.  Why not just write a simple loop to count the special characters?  It will be faster and other developers will thank you.

Comment: @VGR I hope you must be aware that every project or task has its own requirements.

Comment: Is it a requirement to do this all with a single regular expression?  `s.chars().filter(c -> "$@!%*?&\n".indexOf(c) >= 0).count() <= 3` seems a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @VGR Is it a requirement to do this all with a single regular expression. YES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to match max 3 special characters:

```bash
^(?:[^$@!%*?&]*[$@!%*?&]){0,3}[^$@!%*?&]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/frTYs5/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[^$@!%*?&]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not inside `[...]`
  - `[$@!%*?&]`: Match one of these characters inside `[...]`
- `){0,3}`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 ot 3 times
- `[^$@!%*?&]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not inside `[...]`
- `$`: End